# How to set a reference to a property placeholder for an ESB mule enumerated type attribute

Tags: properties, mule, scheduler, enumeration, timeunit

I am currently developping an ESB (3.7.0 CE) mule application and I am using Poll component with fixed-frequency-scheduler. I would like to externalize timeUnit scheduler's attribute as below:

```
<poll doc:name="Poll">
<fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="${scheduler.frequency}" timeUnit="${scheduler.timeUnit}" startDelay="${scheduler.startDelay}" />
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_RSS_Request_Configuration" path="${dmp.url.token}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP GET RSS"/>
</poll>
```

However, an exception is thrown during deployment:

```
2016-11-25 10:13:29,265 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] ERROR org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication - null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${scheduler.timeUnit}' is not a valid value for 'NMTOKEN'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

The explanation might be that NMTOKEN does not allow using of $, {, } which are required for defining properties. But the question is how this could be overcome.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a context property placeholder in you mule config xml?

Like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:somefile.properties" />
```

Comment: I am using the default mule-app.properties to register the properties, so I have not declared any properties files in my mule config xml.